# Stuck with parsing JSON with Android, using JIRA rest API

Tags: java, android, rest, jira-rest-java-api

I am kinda new to Android and Rest API. I hit a problem I have no idea what to do next. I search here but everthing is outdated. Could you point me to right direction ? Would appriciate some code with explanation.

However I am trying to login and get all project "Key" from Jira [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/project-getProject) and view them in TextView.

I came this far :

```
public class TimeTrackingJira extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textViewIssue, textViewProject;
    private static final String urlConn = "https://xy.atlassian.net";
    private static final String USERNAME = "xx";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "yy";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_tracking_jira);
        textViewProject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProject);
        textViewIssue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewIssue);
        try {
            Test();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void Test () throws IOException {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            }
        });
        URL url = new URL(urlConn);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {

        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Previus I tried to use my java code from java project, but seems like library is outdated and I had problems with http client is different version as android use.

Library I used was :
compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-android-client-core:4.0.7'

code :

```
private void Test () throws Exception {
        sproject = "PROJECT NAME : \n";
        sissue   = "ISSUE KEY : \n";
        URI jiraServerUri = new URI(URL);
        final AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        try {
            Iterable<BasicProject> project = restClient.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().claim();
            for(int i = 0; i < Iterables.size(project); i++) {
                String p = Iterables.get(project,i).getName(); // We have 2 project 0 - first 1- second

                //System.out.println("PROJECT NAME : " + p);
                sproject = sproject + p + "\n" ;
                textViewProject.setText(sproject);
                SearchResult searchQuery = restClient.getSearchClient().searchJql("project = \"" + p + "\"").claim();
                Iterable<Issue> issues = searchQuery.getIssues();
                for(int j = 0; j < Iterables.size(issues); j++) {
                    String issue = Iterables.get(issues,j).getKey();
                    sissue = sissue + issue + "\n";
                    textViewIssue.setText(sissue);
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            // cleanup the restClient
            restClient.close();
        }
    }
```

Edit: Basicly I am trying to do something similar in REST API as do code above.